# Spring SqlOutParameter is not honouring the parameter type

Tags: sql-server, spring, t-sql, spring-jdbc

I am calling a SP with OUTPUT parameter of `int` type but it seems the returned parameter is in `varchar` anyway:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withProcedureName("spThatReturnsInt")
        .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("ret", Types.INTEGER))
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .execute();
```

The above code ended up with an SQL exception:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

And the SP is defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spThatReturnsInt @ret int OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a sql exception was thrown. Doesn't look like the procedure got to the point of actually returning your int value, but got an exception instead.Try running it in your SQL Server Management studio and make sure it actually runs and returns an integer.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not throw any exception if I change the type to VARCHAR.

Comment: There you have it. Whatever query you have inside that stored procedure is trying to return a varchar type parameter, and you are trying to force it to return an integer, and that's where you get the error. Maybe it actually returns an integer string , like '1' as opposed to 1, in which case all you have to do is cast it as an int. If not, you might have to live with it returning a varchar or change the actual query inside

Comment: Yeah, exactly like what you said, for whatever reason the return parameter was defined as VARCHAR by jdbc driver, but as you can see my SP creation has it as int. Anyway, I found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, the issue has gone when I changed from `SqlOutParameter` to `SqlInOutParameter`. i.e.:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withProcedureName("spThatReturnsInt")
        .declareParameters(new SqlInOutParameter("ret", Types.INTEGER))
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .execute();
```

I have no clue why, it just works.